# Problem with connecting QLabel to QSlider

Tags: qt, qlabel, qslider, qt-connection

I have a problem. I've created a class, in which I have a slider and a label. I want to connect these with the QObject::connect, but when I do it, nothing happens. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

**My class:**

```
class Loads :public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QSlider slider;
    QLabel label;
    QMainWindow okno;
    Loads();

private:
    int wart;

public slots:
    void zmiana(int li);

};
```

**Class "Loads" constructor:**

```
Loads::Loads()
{
    okno.setGeometry(300,300,300,300);
    label.setParent(&okno);
    slider.setParent(&okno);
    label.setGeometry(0,0,300,200);
    slider.setGeometry(0,200,300,100);
    slider.setMinimum(1);
    slider.setMaximum(30);
    label.setText("0");
    wart=0;
    QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL( slider.valueChanged(int)), this , SLOT( zmiana(int)) );
    okno.show();
}
```

**My "zmiana" slot**

```
void Loads::zmiana(int li)
{
        wart=li;
        label.setText(QString::number(li));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL( slider.valueChanged(int)), this , SLOT( zmiana(int)) );
```

I don't think that's correct, you're connecting the signal of the `Loads` object to the slot but the `Loads` object is *not* the one generating the signal, the `slider` object is doing that.

Hence I think you'll need `slider` as the first argument, not `this`. Using `this` as the third argument is okay, I believe, since the slot *does* belong to the `Loads` object.